# Difficulty booting 2013 iMac from external SSD via USB 3.0

Tags: imac, ssd, startup

Recently, I have been running into difficulty booting into macOS using an external SSD connected via USB 3.0.

Backstory... 2013 Imac was working great for about 5 years until the internal HDD started to fail.  Rather than replace the internal drive (due to difficulty, Apple changed the screen from magnetic to sticky adhesive), I bought Samsung SSD, cloned the internal drive via SuperDuper, set as default startup disk, and connected via USB 3.0.

Strategy worked awesome for 2 years to give an old mac new life and OS has run flawlessly until recently when a macOS update was installed and the computer restarted and the external drive/operating system could not be found.  The SSD is fine, and I tested its functionality on another computer.  Any time I startup and hold Option, reset SMC, PRAM, unplug the external and plug it back in, switch SSD usb port, change SSD usb cable (and even swapped SSD enclosure), still the same issue.  I cannot get the iMac to recognize the external SSD as a valid startup disk.

I ran into this issue before on another macOS update and it randomly corrected itself after I furiously went through all of the options above 3 or 4 times to no avail.  I just came back to the computer a different day, and it restarted into macOS flawlessly again.   This time, I am having no such luck and I am super bummed.  What haven't I tried to fix it again? Should I reset the PRAM/SMC another 3 or 4 times?

Comment: 1. Were you trying to upgrade to Big Sur?
2. Do you have another computer that you can use to mount the SSD?

Comment: @pion: Apple does not support Big Sur installations on 2013 iMacs. See [macOS Big Sur - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp833?locale=en_US). In other words, the OP can not upgrade to Big Sur.

Comment: @David Anderson: Good observation. That at least rules out the Big Sur upgrade bug.